# CoffeeScript: How to use both fat arrow and this?

Tags: coffeescript, this, arrow-functions

I have a coffeescript class that has some jquery event listeners. I would like to use the fat arrow `=>` to avoid having to reference the class, but I still need a reference to the element that would usually be used with `this`. How can I use both?

```
class PostForm
    constructor: ->
        $('ul.tabs li').on 'click', =>
            tab = $(this)
            @highlight_tab(tab)
            @set_post_type(tab.attr('data-id'))

    highlight_tab: (tab)->
        tab.addClass 'active'

    set_post_type: (id) ->
        $('#post_type_id').val(id)
```

Comment: Can you describe a bit more what you want to do? Where do you want to use (this), and what part of the above is not working the way you want? IOW, what object do you want `this` to be a reference to? The target of the event, the PostForm class instance, etc?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

CoffeeScript links both `this` and `@` to the outer context, therefore you cannot access the context that jQuery provided (aka the desired "this"). Use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) instead:

```
class PostForm
    constructor: ->
        $('ul.tabs li').on 'click', (event) =>
            tab = $(event.target)
            @highlight_tab(tab)
```

Comment: `event.target` saves us in `Backbone.js` as well

Comment: `event.target` is also _far less confusing_ to someone who doesn't know the DOM rules around `this`.

Comment: Note that you probably want evt.currentTarget if you do events with selectors.  See http://codepen.io/ddopson/pen/erLiv

Comment: what do you do on d3? callbacks in d3 give you the object (not DOM)

Comment: I don't know if this was true when you wrote it, but event.target sometimes returns a different element than 'this'.

'this' on a click event callback returns the element that triggered the callback, while event.target returns the element the mouse was over when the click event fired (which is often a child element of some sort)

Answer (score 36):

### Using evt.currentTarget

You should probably use [`evt.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) (which is equivalent to `this`) instead of [`evt.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) (which isn't).  If the node that you are tapping for `click` notifications has child nodes, `evt.target` might be one of those child nodes instead of the node you added the `click` handler to.

See http://codepen.io/ddopson/pen/erLiv for a demo of this behavior. (click on the inner red box to see that `currentTarget` points at the red div while `target` points at outer blue div that the event handler is registered on)

```
$('ul.tabs li').on 'click', (event) =>
  tab = $(event.currentTarget)
  @highlight_tab(tab)
```

### Answer to the question asked - getting both `=>` and `this`:

You can do the following...

```
$('ul.tabs li').on 'click', (event) =>
  tab = $(` this `)     # MAKE SURE TO ADD THE SPACES AROUND `this`
  @highlight_tab(tab)
```

The spaces are critical as they prevent Coffee from munching `this` into `_this`.

### Using `self` and `->`

Alternatively, do the following ...

```
self = this
$('ul.tabs li').on 'click', (event) ->
  tab = $(this)
  self.highlight_tab(tab)
```

This is similar to CQQL's answer, except that I prefer the idiomatic use of `self` as the variable name; my [VIM syntax highlighting rules](https://github.com/ddopson/dotfiles/blob/master/.vim/bundle/coffee-script.vim/syntax/coffee.vim#L66) color `self` as a "special" variable just as it would for `this`, `arguments`, or `prototype`.

Comment: self = this is exactly what I do. It works perfectly!

Comment: event.currentTarget is not actually the same as 'this', at least for jquery on click events. It may sometimes have the same value, but it also might not, depending on circumstances. 'this' refers to the element that was clicked, while event.currentTarget returns the element that was watching for click events.

Comment: @GlyphGryph - Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

I prefer this version, because I can understand it more easily.

```
class PostForm
    constructor: ->
        post_form = this

        $('ul.tabs li').on 'click', (event) ->
            tab = $(this)
            post_form.highlight_tab(tab)
```

Comment: How would you go about accessing post_form from another function on the class?

Comment: Class methods should be able to use `this` normally to refer to the current instance of `PostForm`.

Comment: Thanks @CQQL :) I elaborated on my question with an answer that shows what I figured out in the end. Initially I wanted to hand the callback function directly to the  `click` handler but then realised I should first wrap that in an anonymous function that grabs `this` and passes it to the named function via `self` in order to have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to access variables set in the constructor from your functions. This would be how you do it (the key is calling the function via `self` while first extracting `this` with a thin arrow):

```
class PostForm
    constructor: ->
        self = this

        @some_contrived_variable = true

        $('ul.tabs li').on 'click', ->
            tab = $(this)
            self.highlight_tab(tab)
            self.set_post_type(tab.attr('data-id'))

    highlight_tab: (tab) ->
        # Because of the fat arrow here you can now access @ again
        if @some_contrived_variable
            tab.addClass 'active'

    set_post_type: (id) ->
        $('#post_type_id').val(id)
```

BTW: [This is a great explanation of when to use the fat and thin arrow.](https://gist.github.com/meandmax/355b7433eb68b47540c5)

Summary:

1. Do you use this (@) in the function?
2. Do you want to execute the function later, possibly from a different scope?

Comment: You can access `@` in `highlight_tab` because `highlight_tab` is called on `self`, not because of the fat arrow. The fat arrow does not make a difference. You can try it yourself by compiling both versions.